# How to write code so multiple UITextField's to appear in one cell on the UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I'm having the user input four pieces of information into four different UITextField's (homeTeam, visitingTeam, homeScore and visitingScore).  I am very new to Swift and am trying to figure out how to connect those four UITextFields so they show in the UITableViewCell's.  I feel like this should be very easy but I am very new to Swift.

I have attached an image so hopefully it makes it easier to understand.  I want the information from these four textFields to be displayed in one cell of the ui table view so it shows the two teams and the score of the game.  Does that help?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVI8S.png)

Comment: Give more information about the table view, how many cells, is it in different controller? Where are those textfield in? Better give a screenshot

Comment: You want 4 text fields in 1 cell? Your description doesn't suggest so

Comment: I added an image hopeful that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach 4 `IBActions` to the 4 `UITextFields`, that update 4 different variables.

In the table, add 4 label outlets (you can make the table static, and force 4 rows if you want).

Then when you segue from one viewController to the other, pass the 4 variables into the new segue controller, and update the outlets to display the appropriate data.